# Rails - Using Conditionals inside a Hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to use a conditional statement inside this `content_tag` hash so that when `'hdrs'` includes any value inside of `'fields'`, the `:class=>'foo'` would be set as `:class=>'bar'`. Is it possible to put a inline conditional inside the `content_tag` hash? If so, how?

```
fields = ['name']

headers.collect { |hdrs| content_tag('th', hdrs, {:nowrap=>true, :class=>'foo', :name=>hdrs}) }
```

Comment: why don't you call another method with the logic inside?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
headers.collect { |hdrs| content_tag('th', hdrs, {:nowrap=>true, :class=>(fields.include?(hdrs) ? 'bar' : 'foo'), :name=>hdrs}) }
```